# Parse Javascript as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, rendering

I have tried everything. My code doesn't render as HTML, instead it is just raw text.

This is my code:

```
 $('#question').parseHTML(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There is no jQuery function like that. There's `$.parseHTML()`, but no `parseHTML` method on jQuery instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to use `html()` as output?

```
$('#question').html(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
```

Or like this with `$.parseHTML` which is to parse a string into an array of DOM nodes.

```
var html = $.parseHTML(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
$('#question').html(html);
```

Comment: No. My code is based on this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/267/) . That's where the problem with html parsing begins

Comment: In this fiddle above, line 175 : I replaced `.text` with `.html`... And it is working. Ho... You can't see the word "came" in bold because the whole sentence is inside a `h2` defined as `bold` on line 40 of your CSS.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks. I would have upvoted your answer if you had one. And thanks jrbedard for the clarification.

Comment: No problem! ;) But @jrbedard deserves the correct answer green checkmark since he was right even without the fiddle context.